# Call to Angular service resulting in interminable loop

Tags: angular

I am invoking the getSubtotal() method from the CartComponent.html template as shown:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 bg-white text-right">
   <p class="font-bold">
      {{cartService.getSubtotal() | currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow'}}
   </p>
</div>
```

This is the getSubtotal method of CartService which simply logs the cartItems object for now:

```
public getSubtotal() {
   var subtotal:number = 0;

   console.log('getSubtotal() ', this.cartItems)
   // for(let item of this.cartItems) {
   //   subtotal += this.getItemPrice(item);
   // }

   return subtotal;
 }
```

Apparently the getSubtotal method is being called interminably. It prints this in a loop:

```
getSubtotal()  (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: If I were you, I would call `getSubtotal()` from `CartComponent.ts`, and store the result in a variable so that you don't need to call it from the template

Comment: It gets called for each change detection that runs. It should be called once from the component and then bound to a variable which is then rendered.

Comment: If you want your cart to be updated each time an item is added, increase, decrease, etc.. you need to use event emitter. You then subscribe it in your cart service. You can also use DoCheck but I would not recommend it.